# i'm Getting error while using FirestoreRecyclerOptions What sholud i do

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Cannot resolve symbol 'FirestoreRecyclerOptions'

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:8.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.4.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

---

```
firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query=firestore.collection("playlist");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<pagl> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<pagl[enter image description here][1]>()
                .setQuery(query, pagl.class)
                .build();
```

Comment: Did you import it?

Comment: Have you tried m0skit0's recommendation? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i add implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.1' this dependency and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added a dependency for FirebaseUI for the Realtime Database, but your code is trying to use FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the UI for one can't be used with the other.

To use FirebaseUI with Firestore, add this dependency:

```
// FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.1'
```

Also see the documentation on [installing FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation).